# Can I use the Find My service for AirPod Pros (2nd gen) without an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: android, airpods

I've got an Android phone and I'm *extremely* prone to losing wireless ear buds. I've just lost yet another pair. I need to buy new ones. I'm considering getting AirPods (2nd gen Pros), partly because they seem to have good tracking features (i.e. Apple's Find My service).

I'm concerned that I won't be able to benefit from it because I have an Android phone. That said, I do have a MacBook Pro which I would also be pairing the AirPods with.

If I buy AirPods, and use them occasionally with my MacBook, but mostly with my Android phone, will I still be able to use Apple's AirPods tracking services, like Find My?

Specifically, if I pair them with my Macbook pro and also with my android phone, and then misplace them, will I be able to locate them with Find My?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207581), you need to **set up** Find My with an *Apple* device (iPhone, iPad).

> To find your AirPods, ***you need to set up Find My with your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch that you use with your AirPods***. Before you try to find your AirPods, you should update to the latest version of iOS or iPadOS, or macOS.

When they are used with non-Apple devices, they become plain Bluetooth devices without the advanced functionality like Find My.

> If I buy AirPods, and use them occasionally with my MacBook

Unfortunately, they need to be paired to an iPhone/iPad (not a Mac) to utilize the advanced features; think of them as an extension of the mobile device much like the Apple Watch is an extension of the iPhone.

Comment: See edit in question - new final paragraph

Comment: The first sentence from the Apple Support document addresses that:  it needs to be set up by an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.  The Mac can update it's Bluetooth firmware, but Find My is done *through* the iPhone/iPad